# I can't find out how to show the average FPS in a game on an On Screen Display with MSI Afterburner

Tags: windows-10, windows-installer, msi-afterburner

I am using MSI Afterburner to show the GPU and CPU temperature which works perfectly fine, but I can't find out why it doesn't let me show the average FPS. Everything else works. Has anybody had this problem before and know how to solve it?

I am using Windows 10.

Comment: What version of MSI Afterburner are you using?

Comment: I am using MSI Afterburner v4.6.1